# How to import products very fast into my site from csv file

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.7

Iam new to magento..

I have a csv file that contains lots of products, when I try to run using Dataflow, its taking too much time to import products from csv to my site..

Do you have any idea on how to increase the speed of it or any good extension that does this job?

pls kindly tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that [MAGMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) is the best way in the terms of **speed**, simplicity and scalability. And it's 100% free and open source.

With MAGMI, you don't need to deal with any coding, you just need to setup this tool into your Magento root folder and then configure it properly as some specific types of product data require some "fine tuning". I.e. if you need to import products with images and media gallery - make sure to install "Image item processor" plugin and assign proper images folder to look up for images during import in MAGMI settings. If you need to import configurable products - make sure to add required columns and install proper plugin "Configurable items processor" etc.

MAGMI supports all possible product data - it allows to import categories and create them on fly, it allows to import grouped products, products links like cross-sells, up-sells etc.

Also for those people who is not technically savvy in terms of SQL and Magento import, there is a [tool](http://productuploader.magelynx.com) which integrates MAGMI into Magento admin and makes the configuration easier.

Comment: hi rob, could you please reply here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/remote-images-not-displaying-after-running-magmi

Answer (score 0):

The best way - is to use script, that running from a shell. But to do that - you must write that script. Tt's not hard, when you sell a similar products on your shop (like only watches). Beacause if you sell many different product groups - it's hard to code import of all atributes and product options. By the way: import of ~2000 products with their cathegories, custom options and attributes takes ~ 30 minutes. (Some programmers,maybe, can make a script, running faster).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to upload existing products and update any attributes then please keep sku and those columns which are going to update. It will works fast.